# I'm unable to grant permission for impersonation in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to get the impersonation working in order to request an authentication token.

I'm using the recipe from github: https://github.com/docusign/OAuth_JWT_recipes/blob/master/node.js/jwt_test.js. When I open the granting URL, the message `The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign` is popping up. This is it looks in the admin control panel: [image: Docusign screenshot]
And this is the redirect URI in the code:

[image: Redirect URI from the code]

The URL that is generated looks like

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code
&scope=signature%20impersonation
&client_id=fe8cc54a-884f-48e3-8a83-95cc12764803
&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com`.

I have also tried to encode the URI like so:

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code
&scope=signature%20impersonation
&client_id=fe8cc54a-884f-48e3-8a83-95cc12764803
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.docusign.com`.

But to no avail.

How can I debug this? What details might I be missing from this puzzle? Any hints or suggested directions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www` is missing in your Integrator Key's RedirectUri. Redirect URI should `match` exactly between `IntegratorKey` and the `Consent URL`.[image] change it to `https://www.docusign.com`

Comment: You are right. This Docusign stuff makes me unconcentrated, thank you very much!